# Mysterious Segmentation Fault on Destruction

Tags: c++, templates, tree, segmentation-fault

In the song "God Wrote in LISP Code" they say that "only God can make a tree" in C (or C++); I've begun to believe.

I have the beginnings of a tree class, but my class segfaults on destruction saying that the error is my the queue `free_spaces`, though I don't see why. Additionally, random bugs seem to lurk here and there.

I've never used templates like this before, so maybe there's some hidden abuse going on there.

Any help would be appreciated.

**header.h**

```
#include<vector>
#include<queue>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class node {
    public:
        int leftChild,parent;
        bool empty;
        T data;
        node() : leftChild(-1), parent(-1), empty(true) {}
};

template <class T>
class AvlTree {
    private:
        vector< node<T> > nodes;
        queue<int> free_spaces;
        int root;

        int newnode(int parent){
            int index=nodes.size();
            nodes.push_back(node<T>());
            nodes[index].parent=parent;
            return index;
        }

    public:
        AvlTree(){
            nodes.push_back(node<T>());
            root=0;
        }

        void grow(){
            nodes[root].leftChild=newnode(root);
        }
};
```

**main.h**

```
#include "header.h"

int main(){
    AvlTree<int> bob;
    bob.grow();
    cerr<<"Made it to end."<<endl;
}
```

Comment: I love the quote from the Lisp song. Have you tried to run it in a debugger?

Comment: I have, but the place where the bug shows up makes no sense to me: it occurs in the destructor of the `free_spaces` queue. My thought is that memory is somehow getting written which should not. I'm using g++ 4.7.2, if that is helpful.

Comment: For those who enjoyed the song quote, [lyrics are here](http://www.songworm.com/lyrics/songworm-parody/EternalFlame.html) and an [MP3 is here](http://www.prometheus-music.com/audio/eternalflame.mp3).

Comment: If you suspect that access `vector` elements with `at` instead of with `[]` and see if you get a runtime error. `nodes` is declared right before your unused `free_spaces`.

Comment: @honk, I'm afraid I don't follow your suggestion.

Comment: @Richard: `nodes[parent]` doesn't check if `parent` is a valid index while `nodes.at(parent)` will check and throw a runtime error if it is invalid.

Comment: Thanks, @hook. I tried this and the situation remains unchanged.

Comment: Just for history, after checking the code and tracing it, I answered that it seemed to be a compiler bug with g++. I even found a cure (explicit initialization). Lesson: even if there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code, and even if a cure that would apparently only work for a compiler bug, works, it needs not be a compiler bug! <g>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem lies in the following line of code:

```
nodes[parent].leftChild=newnode(parent);
```

Simply replacing it with this fixes it:

```
int left = newnode(parent);
nodes[parent].left = left;
```

This ultimately boils down to the order of evaluation. The thing is that `newnode()` function modifies the vector length. Doing that may force `std::vector<>` to re-allocate memory in order to grow (i.e. if current capacity is not enough). If you hit on that case, `nodes[parent].left` expression on the left side, if evaluated before the `newnode()` call, will point to a potentially invalid memory location.

Comment: Of course! It's so obvious once you see it. Is there any way to force the "correct" order of operations without an intermediate variable?

Comment: @Richard: No, the order of evaluation is unspecified in this case and compilers are allowed to do what they think is better. You should just stay away from such constructs. There are tons of UB examples related to order of evaluation (i.e. `*x^=*y^=*x^=*y`).

Comment: +1 for following up on that even after my misleading answer that it was probably a compiler bug (with cure).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: You got me thinking :)

Answer (score 0):

Valgrind shows this error:

```
==23995== Invalid write of size 4
==23995==    at 0x400F68: AvlTree<int>::grow() (/tmp/header.h:39)
==23995==    by 0x400BC6: main (/tmp/t.cc:5)
==23995==  Address 0x5967770 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 16 free'd
==23995==    at 0x4C29DFD: operator delete(void*) (/coregrind/m_replacemalloc/vg_replace_malloc.c:456)
==23995==    by 0x401FC5: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<node<int> >::deallocate(node<int>*, unsigned long) (/usr/include/c++/4.4/ext/new_allocator.h:95)
==23995==    by 0x40187B: std::_Vector_base<node<int>, std::allocator<node<int> > >::_M_deallocate(node<int>*, unsigned long) (/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_vector.h:146)
==23995==    by 0x401743: std::vector<node<int>, std::allocator<node<int> > >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<node<int>*, std::vector<node<int>, std::allocator<node<int> > > >, node<int> const&) (/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/vector.tcc:361)
==23995==    by 0x40106B: std::vector<node<int>, std::allocator<node<int> > >::push_back(node<int> const&) (/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_vector.h:741)
==23995==    by 0x40131A: AvlTree<int>::newnode(int) (/tmp/header.h:24)
==23995==    by 0x400F67: AvlTree<int>::grow() (/tmp/header.h:39)
==23995==    by 0x400BC6: main (/tmp/t.cc:5)
```

That should be enough for you to find the bug.

Comment: The syntax here is somewhat cryptic to me. The deallocates are perhaps unexpected. It's like the thing that is being pushed is not making it in, but putting it in a temporary variable didn't seem to fix this either.

Comment: To keep it simple, in most cases just look at the first error (Invalid Write of Size 4) and focus on the given line. It was indeed where the problem was.